# anaconda navigator not start direct without source command

Tags: anaconda

when i run following command  
 `source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root` 
it is work fine. I don't want to run this command every time. give me any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can write script (.sh) for that.

```
STARTPATH=$(pwd)
cd ~/anaconda3/bin
case $1 in
    -j|--jupyter)
        shift
        source activate
        jupyter-lab
        ;;
    -n|--navigator)
        shift
        source activate
        anaconda-navigator
        ;;
esac
source deactivate
cd $STARTPATH
```

Then you can run the script by ./ or you can put the script in `/usr/local/bin` and make it executable `chmod +x *yourfile*.sh`.

After that you should be able to type in your console: `*yourfile* -n` and this will launch anaconda navigator.